# Dissect a rectangle $a \times 1$ by a smooth monotone function connecting opposite corners so the areas are $1$ and $a-1$

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry

Let $f(x)$ be continuous, infinitely differentiable and increasing on $x \in (0,1)$, and $a$ - a *given* real number such that $a>1$. The following conditions should hold:

$$f(0)=0$$

$$f(1)=a$$

$$\int^1_0 f(x)~dx=a-1$$

Find all $f(a)$.

[image]

One such case (and motivation for this problem) is the exponential function:

$$a=e-1$$

$$f(x)=e^x-1$$

However, there is another solution:

$$f(x)=(e-1)x^{1/(e-2)}$$

[image]

In general for powers of $x$ for $p>0$:

$$f(x)=ax^p$$

$$a \int^1_0 x^p~dx=a-1$$

$$a=\frac{p+1}{p}>1$$

$$p=\frac{1}{a-1}$$

There are also polynomial solutions possible.

> Can all such functions for a given number $a$ be found? Would these functions always be 'close' together like in the plot above?

**Edit**

Yes, I see now, there are infinite amount of solutions, however properly defining the functions satisfying these conditions is hard. For example in the case above I was able to find another family of solutions:

$$f(x)=(e-1-B \sin \omega)x^p+B \sin (w x)$$

$$B=\frac{\omega (p(e-2)-1)}{(p+1)(1-\cos \omega )-\omega \sin \omega}$$

The condition of function being monotone on $(0,1)$ means that $f'(x)$ should have no zeros in this interval. Even for simple functions the general inequalities for the constants can only be solved numerically.

This function is somewhat easy. For example, here it is with $\omega=\frac{\pi}{3}$ (a) and $\omega=\frac{5 \pi}{6}$ (b) and for $p=1,2,\dots,10$ in each case:

[image]

However, the last case of $p=10$ is already incorrect, since the function has a local minimum.

Comment: Yes, there are *lots* of solutions.  There are even many more that you can't describe.  You can add a bump function to anything you have described as long as you make sure it doesn't make the function decrease.  I don't think there is a reasonable answer to the question.

Comment: Since $a$ is assumed $>1$ the value $f(a)$ is undefined.

Comment: Adding in for given $a$, doesn't really change anything.  There are still *lots* of choices